# Unknown entity type: Magento\Bundle\Model\Selection\Interceptor requested

Tags: magento2, bundled-product

How to solve this error Unknown entity type:

> Magento\Bundle\Model\Selection\Interceptor requested

when I tried to add Bundle products options.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is a Magento 2 core bug.
I have fixed it in my [`mage2pro/core`](https://github.com/mage2pro/core) package:
https://github.com/mage2pro/core/blob/7.2.6/Framework/etc/di.xml#L117-L127
https://github.com/mage2pro/core/blob/7.2.6/Framework/Plugin/EntityManager/TypeResolver.php#L1-L20

Answer (score -1):

Try clearing your generated folder and run `bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Comment: Nope; nothing to change. Still showing error.